# Combine Image With Text as a

Tags: button, imageview, imagebutton

What are these objects? Are they buttons?

[image: buttons]

and how can I create one of them?

[image: buttons]

is it an imagebutton? Or button with some attributes?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly they use, but an HTML beginner can create it like this:
[HTML code](https://jsfiddle.net/tt5syvf4/16/)

Answer (score 0):

The second image might be something like [HTML/CSS cards](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_cards.asp) (how-to tutorial) or [Bootstrap Cards](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/card/) (examples)